# Efficient sorting of rotated N bit words

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bit-manipulation

Given an array `arr` which contains N-bit words in sorted order, is there an efficient algorithm to sort the result of rotation all elements in the array left one bit - preferably with a smaller constant factor than using radix/american flag sort.

```
sortRotated(arr : Array<Word32>)
  for(I in indices arr)
    arr[i] = rotateLeft(arr[i],1) // 0bXn..n => 0bn..nX
  efficientSort(arr)
```

It feels like it should be possible in linear time, we know something about the ordering of the elements in the groups which match `0b0..0`, `0b0..1`, `0b1..0` and `0b1..1`.

Comment: Sure. You know that for all the values that had a 0 leading bit before rotation, the rest of the bits were in sorted order. Same for those with a leading 1. So all that's necessary is to merge those two lists in O(n) time.  The new rightmost bits will be taken care of at the same time.

Comment: Interesting task! Just a silly thought though: If you rotate them, you're not treating them as binary numbers but as vectors of bits. Other than for numbers, there is no "inherent" ordering like ascending or descending, so why do you need one here? If the point is e.g. efficient lookup (thinking of a set), you could possibly tailor the lookup to know by how many bits the sequence is rotated. Same goes for other algorithms that require an ordering.

Comment: So the real goal here is to find groups of integers with low hamming distance to each other (say a distance of up to 3). I'm sure there's a better algorithm than just sorting all rotations and finding spans with low hamming distance (this idea is based on an idea from http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of the input array as two partitions. The first is a sorted list of all words with leading 0 bit. The second is the same with leading 1 bit. These bits get rotated to the rightmost postion. What's left is two sorted lists. A single merge pass sorts them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rotate_and_resort(unsigned *a, int n) {
  // rotate
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = (a[i] << 1) | (a[i] >> 31);

  // resort; find the first word with rightmost bit 1
  int rm1;
  for (rm1 = 0; rm1 < n && (a[rm1] & 1) == 0; ++rm1) /* skip */;

  // If all the words end with the same bit, we're done.
  if (rm1 == 0 || rm1 == n) return;

  // make a temp copy for merging
  unsigned t[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) t[i] = a[i];

  // merge
  int i = 0, j = rm1, k = 0;
  while (k < n)
    a[k++] = i < rm1 && t[i] < t[j] ? t[i++] : t[j++];
}

int cmp_unsigned(const void *va, const void *vb) {
  unsigned a = *(unsigned*)va, b = *(unsigned*)vb;
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned n = 100, a[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = rand() ^ (rand() << 16);
  qsort(a, n, sizeof *a, cmp_unsigned);
  rotate_and_resort(a, n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) printf("%u\n", a[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

There's a fancier merge algorithm where the temp space is at most half of the input size.  Here I've used the simplest algorithm, which makes a full copy.

Comment: Great response, I feel like I was really close to this answer but didn't quite get there - initially I'd been looking to partition by the high order bit first, and though that if that was done stably then the result would be sorted but this is actually the correct way to do it

Comment: »`fancier merge algorithm where the temp space is at most half of the input size`«. As far as I know even an [in-place merge](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-merge-sort/) is possible.

Comment: @Socowi The link you provided needs O(n^2) time, which defeats the whole purpose of a special sort for rotated values. There exist O(n) in-place merges, but they rely on some fairly exotic number theory to quickly identify permutation cycles. They're hard to get right and even harder to make fast.

Comment: @Gene Thanks for the hint. Admittedly I did not really look at the link I posted. The part »`// Merges two subarrays of arr[]. Inplace Implementation`« was enough for me. I'm baffled that someone took the time to write a tutorial on how to implement a sorting algorithm in O(n^2 log(n)) when even the most straightforward algorithms like insertion sort take "only" O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be to identify the four blocks of your data:

- `0b00...` (becomes `0b0...0`),
- `0b01...` (becomes `0b1...0`),
- `0b10...` (becomes `0b0...1`),
- `0b11...` (becomes `0b1...1`),

Note that within all four blocks, the data is still sorted, except for the last bit. So first in one pass we can correct that. (This can be the same pass that identifies the extent of the four blocks.) If you have no repeating elements, it is as simple as finding any odd K that is followed by K-1, and swapping them. If you have repeats, then you'll have to have mini-sorts of `K` and `K-1` regions, so it's a little bit more involved, but not by much.

Then you're left with basically four sorted arrays, where all elements of 1st and 3rd (`0b0...`) will always be smaller than all elements of 2nd and 4th (`0b1...`). Thus, applying merge sort to 1st and 3rd, then concatenating the result with the merge sort of 2nd and 4th, will give you the correct result.

EDIT: sorry for lots of rewrites, I just found one mistake in my logic after another as I was writing :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was what I was thinking too, though Gene above has hit the nail on the dead by identifying that after rotations, there are two sub arrays which have 0 as their low bit and then 1 as their low bit, but these subarrays are still sorted, and that merging those is trivial.